# get id value to function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to load some PHP page to div tags with this, but this code does not work;

```html
<a href="#" id="dahili"><span>Dahili Branşlar</span></a>
    <a href="#" id="cerrahi" ><span>Cerrahi Branşlar</span></a></li>
     <script>
 var yuklenecek = document.getElementById(id);
$("#"+yuklenecek).on("click", function(){
$("#orta_load").load(yuklenecek+".php");
});
</script>
<div id="orta_load">
    when ı click to buton that which ı choose : should load dahili.php or cerrahi.php page in here
</div>
```

Comment: Surely it does not seems good way to ask question.

Comment: `var yuklenecek = document.getElementById(id);`  what is id?

Comment: ı want to get id from link id 
is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```js
$(".loaddiv").click(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr("id") + ".php";
  $("#orta_load").load(url);
  console.log("loading " + url);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="dahili" class="loaddiv"><span>Dahili Branşlar</span></a>
<a href="#" id="cerrahi" class="loaddiv"><span>Cerrahi Branşlar</span></a>
<div id="orta_load">
  when ı click to buton that which ı choose : should load dahili.php or cerrahi.php page in here
</div>
```

Note how the jQuery function assigns the click handler to each `<a>`, then uses its `id` to determine the php document.

Comment: hı thank you again. And ı have a new problem now.
how can ı display "loading..png" when the page is loading

Comment: Simple: insert `$("#orta_load").html("<img src='loading.png'>");` right before `$("#orta_load").load(url);`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. :)

Comment: Hi Chris;
Thank you so much for your help.
---
Now I have another simple problem.
---
How can send data to  another page which is upload?
---
for example, ı have a contact page that name is contact.php.
When ı press submit button ı should send all data to  thanks.php page without refresh the main page

----
I try a lot of ways but ı could not do this. when ı press the button the page is refreshed or it is not send the data 
---
What should I do?

Comment: Send the data using AJAX. Google "send form ajax".